# Python -- how to add an input function under a differently named function

Tags: python, function, input

So, I am just trying to write a simple code to determined 'whether or not a jacket is needed' based on temp being above or below 70degrees.

I am able to simply use an example that I found and it works just fine(below) However, I need this under a function that is titled `Is_a_Jacket_needed()` and everytime I try to put the input in the body or just try to add the input command to request the temp in the parenthesis of the needed function title, I am unable to get it to work. (syntax errors, indentation block expected, etc) but even when I try changing those things, I do not get the question asked and therefore it's no help to me.

(the code that I am using to get the answers is here --- again, I just need it within `def Is_Jacket_Needed():`  )

```py
temperature = int(input('What is the temperature? '))
if temperature > 70:
    print('No need for a Jacket!')
else:
    print('A Jacket is Needed')
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what error you are getting:

test.py

```py
def is_jacket_needed():
    temperature = int(input('What is the temperature? '))
    if temperature > 70:
        print('No need for a Jacket!')
    else:
        print('A Jacket is Needed')
```

```
>>> from test import is_jacket_needed
>>> is_jacket_needed()
What is the temperature? 50
A Jacket is Needed
>>> is_jacket_needed()
What is the temperature? 80
No need for a Jacket!
```

Comment: Thank you both!! Very Helpful. I just needed to add (is_jacket_needed() ) to call the function. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you forgot to add the argument temperature to your function.

```
def is_a_Jacket_needed():
    temperature = int(input("What is the temperature?"))
    if temperature > 70:
        print("No need for a Jacket!")
    else:
        print("A Jacket is Needed")

#Then call your function

is_a_Jacket_needed(70)
is_a_Jacket_needed(75)
```

Comment: your `temperature` argument is being overwritten by the `temperature` inside the function body.

Comment: you are correct, I'm running some code in python right now and I wasn't able to test it and I forgot that I called the input function.